# ExpanderView Interactive item within header

Tags: windows-phone-7, header, interactive

I want to have some interactive item I can click and fire event within header of ExpanderView. This is a normal behavior for item, but I cannot get it working in header.

In my case I have Image with MouseLeftButtonDown

Any ideas ?

Thanks,
Michal

Answer (score 0):

You can change the look and content of the header by changing the HeaderTemplate of the ExpanderView. The HeaderTemplate takes a DataTemplate which can take any controls you which to place.

```
<toolkit:ExpanderView>
    <toolkit:ExpanderView.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                <Button Content="Click Me!" Grid.Column="1"
                        <!-- Use click event to handle within code behind -->
                        Click="OnHeaderBuittonclick"
                        <!-- Use command to handle within view model -->
                        Command="{Binding DoSomethingCommand}"
                        />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:ExpanderView.HeaderTemplate>
</toolkit:ExpanderView>
```

Comment: As I wrote, this is normal for item, but in header, click event or in my case MouseLeftButtonDown does not work because the default behavior is that the entire header is like a button which expands / collapses items. Of course I do have a header template but event is not handled